# Visual Studio 2013 Pirated Risks

Tags: visual-studio, piracy

I currently use express version of Visual Studio 2013, and I am quite satisfied with it. But I now feel the need to use visual studio ultimate version (too big expectations as it is out of my budget)

So, I came across a dealer who claims that he can give me a pirated version of visual studio ultimate 2013 for considerably low price and now I consider what will be the disadvantages of it? In my country (India) this type of thing is popular. So, my question is does microsoft use some kind of system with which it will recognize if the software or product which is developed with visual studio using a pirated copy of visual studio?

My decision totally depends from the answers which I get from you.

Again: Is it recognizable if I use pirated visual studio for developing applications? Be specific.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: It's not very nice of you to ask this here, honestly if you know that you are using a pirate version you can be ready to expect anything.

Comment: [Already discussed...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/use-of-pirated-cracked-software-for-development)

Comment: Are you aware of community edition http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: so in short you are looking to become a thief?.........

Comment: Extremely Sorry I was not much aware. I installed visual studio community now and I'm very happy with it. I even declined the dealer's request. (I was not looking to become a thief, I was asking if i can become one). Thank You anyways for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are no shortage of people who will lecture you on the evils of pirated software... from the unknown quality (you don't know if it contains viruses or malware) to the ethical and legal issues (yes, its illegal, even if you are unlikely to get "caught" even in your country).

There are better alternatives, however.  Microsoft has a number of programs in which you can get very cheap or even free software if you meet certain conditions.  For instance, the DreamSpark program gives you access to commercial versions of Visual Studio and other software for free if you are a student.  It's not the Ultimate version, but it's the Professional Version.

There is also the Microsoft Student Developer Program.

If you own your own business, and meet certain requirements, there is also the BizSpark and WebsiteSpark programs.  This does give you Ultimate access, and if you have your own business (or know someone who does and is willing to foster your membership) then this is a great program.  You get it all for 3 years for no cost.

Finally, there are discounts you can get as well from various sources, and you might check with your local Microsoft offices.  There is also the ActionPack and ActionPack Development & Design programs, again you have to have a business.. but you can probably find a way to make that work if you're creative, and legal and ethical, and its software you can trust.

And of course, there is the Community Edition of Visual Studio, which is a fully featured version of VS and free for anyone who isn't a large business.

Answer (score 0):

microsoft sells licenses to use their software; to be legitimate, U should purchase a license from them.  If, OTOH, U want software for which U don't have to pay (and U want to be legitimate), try an open source compiler, like the MinGW compiler, or the C# scripting engine CS-Script, which works with the CLR of .NET, and which can also generate executables.  i'm not wild about the MS licensing model, because if there's an error in *their* code, i can't do anything about it, but i think it's best to respect it, if for no other reason than to keep them off your back.

if U want to violate the model, which, while admittedly stupid, is their choice and also backed up by the law in my country, U'll get no help from me.